# 0x89721500 error in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015

After installing Visual Studio 2015 from previous 2013 update 4 I was not able to deploy my Windows Phone apps to devices getting error 0x89721500.

Answer (score 6):

I solved just deleting directory "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Phone Tools\CoreCon\11.0" then restarting Visual Studio.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had this error for a long time and did not find a solution, but your hint helped me solving it!

Comment: Same for later VS-Versions (replace path-fragment 11.0 with e.g. 12.0)